# How to delete a custom resource using fabric8io?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, fabric8

Is it possible to delete custom resource using fabric8io?

If not, is it possible using kubectl java client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both is possible.

Fabric8 example:

```
public static Map<String, Object> doDeleteCustomResource(
    KubernetesClient kubernetesClient, CustomResourceDefinitionContext crdContext, String namespace, String name)
    throws IOException{

    if ("Namespaced".equals(crdContext.getScope())) {
        return kubernetesClient.customResource(crdContext).delete(namespace, name);
    } else {
        return kubernetesClient.customResource(crdContext).delete(name);
    }
}
```

Taken from [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.CustomResourceDefinitionContext).

Or similarly using the [Java Operator SDK](https://github.com/java-operator-sdk/java-operator-sdk) which is also using the Fabric8 client:

```
client.customResource(context).delete(name);
```

You can also check out the tests in the [fabric8 client code here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/CustomResourceTest.java) for more examples.